# SharePoint 2013 - Ability to convert HTML to Image

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is there an internal or external package feature that I can activite in sharepoint 2013, which will allow me to convert a portion of HTML on a page to an image?

Answer (score 0):

There is no internal package or feature in Sharepoint 2013, that can allow you to convert a portion of HTML to an image.

You can write you custom code to Convert HTML  to image. 
For examples you can refer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832304/convert-html-string-to-image

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/663153/How-can-I-convert-html-code-to-image-in-csharp-web